# OR gate using XOR gate & AND gate only.

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

A digital circuit supports two operations A ⊕ B and A . B [i.e. XOR , AND operations]
Derive a Boolean Expression for A + B using the above two operations.

Comment: just try: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

The "elongated truth table" for `and (∧)` and `xor (⊕)` is:

```
inputs: |  00 | 01 | 10 | 11
--------+-----+----+----+----
   and: |   0 |  0 |  0 |  1
   xor: |   0 |  1 |  1 |  0
```

If you `xor` those (it should hopefully be obvious now *why* I introduced the concept of an elongated truth table rather than the more classical two-by-two matrix), you get:

```
inputs: | 00 | 01 | 10 | 11
--------+----+----+----+----
   and: |  0 |  0 |  0 |  1
   xor: |  0 |  1 |  1 |  0
--------+----+----+----+----
   xor: |  0 |  1 |  1 |  1
```

which is the same results as you would get from the `or (∨)` function.

Hence, `A ∨ B` is equivalent to `(A ∧ B) ⊕ (A ⊕ B)`.

Answer (score 1):

`a OR b = (a XOR b) XOR (a AND b)`.

Did this by writing out the *truth tables* whilst eating a sandwich:

```
a   b       a AND b       a XOR b
0   0          0             0
0   1          0             1
1   0          0             1
1   1          1             0
```

Comment: Haha, I did exactly the same thing (whilst eating a sandwhich too)!